# Oyama rice cooker - uncooked rice under heating element

Tags: equipment

I accidentally dumped uncooked rice into the Oyama rice cooker under the heating element. I got out what I could, but I can hear I didn't get out all the grains. Shaking / upending the rice cooker doesn't get out all the rice.

Can someone advise how I empty the remaining uncooked rice from under the heating element?

Comment: Make sure it is unplugged and completly discharged, then take it apart, remove the rice and put it back together. It is unclear what kind of answer you expect to get here.

Comment: If I knew how to take the darn thing apart, I'd have done that! Thanks, anyway.

Comment: I am not sure if this question is on topic here then but if you can provide a few images from all sides it would be easier to see how to open it

Comment: Thanks again, Gimli. I'll sort it ... or buy a new rice cooker. Your point is taken that this is off-topic. I thought this was a place to post such a question but I see it isn't.

Comment: @Gimli It looks [on-topic](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to me: "This site is for... If you have a question about: ... Kitchen equipment."

Answer (score 1):

This question is on-topic enough I'll take a shot at it. First of all, don't try to cook with this without getting the rice out as it's a potential fire hazard. You probably know this but it's worth saying!

Now how I'd attack this is to grab a screwdriver and take the thing apart, which is probably easy to do. If you do decide to try it take lots of pictures as you go so you can put it back together.

If that's not a step you're willing to try then it's guaranteed to be physically possible to get the rice out without taking it apart because the rice got in to begin with, it's a matter of getting it tipped to the right angles at the right time. The best way to do this is to shake it - a lot, upside down or tipped the right direction for the rice to come out. Tip it around at all angles, work it loose and then tip it back to the angle it can fall out. Do it again and again until it the rice is gone. It may take awhile doing it this way, and I'd suggest running the machine outside the first time after using this method in case you miss anything.

Comment: Sometime there are stickers hiding screws.  Occassionally they say 'warranty void if removed' or something like that, but that's not legally binding in all areas (especially if your state or country has a 'right to repair' law)

Comment: Also worth mentioning -- the website IFixIt has a lot of disassembly guides, including [for rice cookers](https://www.ifixit.com/Search?query=rice%20cooker) (although, not this particular brand)

Comment: Absolutely right @Joe, there could be stickers, or sometimes the screws are hidden under anti-skid pads. The way I'd look at it is that the warranty was void the second rice got dropped into it, so no harm in trying.

Comment: Thanks all who replied, but since Gimli declared this an off-topic question, I thought I'd not get a response here, so bought another rice cooker. I'll try to not put rice where it's not meant to be. Thanks again.